# Is it possible to prevent "accidental repeat" when accepting empty input on the PHP CLI?

Tags: php, windows

I'm trying to let the user press Enter and then perform an action. I want the user to be required to release the key until the next action is performed. As it is currently, the user can just press and hold Enter and it will just print all these lines because it just executes them one by one. I want the script to halt until they press Enter again.

Example:

```
fgets(STDIN);
echo 'text 1' . PHP_EOL;
fgets(STDIN);
echo 'text 2' . PHP_EOL;
fgets(STDIN);
echo 'text 3' . PHP_EOL;
fgets(STDIN);
echo 'text 4' . PHP_EOL;
fgets(STDIN);
echo 'text 5' . PHP_EOL;
```

Action: User presses Enter.

Result: Everything is printed if you hold down Enter.

Wanted result: "text 1" only, until Enter is again pressed, when "text 2" should appear, and so on.

Requiring the user to type something is not acceptable; it must be a simple Enter keypress (empty input).

Is it possible? I can't tell you how many times I've accidentally performed two actions in a loop because of this bug...

I take it this is impossible, then?

Comment: This is a feature of the keyboard subsystem. If you hold down a key, after a small delay, it will repeat. Php only deals with the resulting keys in the keyboard buffer, what is after the repeat code has run already. You should be able to turn off key repeat in your system settings.

Comment: php doesn't handle keyboard presses, only characters. It gets those from the terminal who gets them from the operating system

Comment: Sure, but you'd think there would be some way to make sure that it's a "new press"?

Comment: STDIN is basically a direct connection to your keyboard buffer. If you let your sausages rest on some key, that key will fill the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the interval between 2 `fgets` calls.

```
$t1 = 0;
function getkey()
{
    global $t1;
    do
    {
        fgets(STDIN);
        $t2 = microtime(true);
        $diff = $t2 - $t1;
        $t1 = $t2;
    }
    while($diff < 0.6);
}

getkey();
echo ...;
getkey();
echo ...;
```

This won't prevent from generating new lines, but the next line won't be executed.

Comment: Well, the problem isn't the time it takes for it to repeat, but that it repeats at all. But it seems like it cannot be avoided?

Comment: As Ferrybig said above, you can disable keyboard repeating by the OS configuration.

Comment: I think the problem is just that you accidentally hold the enter for a bit long time.